# Are closed questions eventually deleted?

Tags: support, closing-questions, deleted-questions, auto-delete

I asked a question about a derivation once, and someone supplied an answer to it. Soon after, the question was closed, however, but I was still discussing and referring to that person's answer there. Now I can't seem to find that question in my list of questions asked, or whenI search words from its title.

Has the question disappeared because closed questions are eventually deleted by moderators? If so, how many days between time of closed to time of deletion?

Comment: To find such questions, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13203/225179.

Comment: Which question was it?  You can see all your deleted questions in your profile: they never disappear permanently (unless you make a special request of the SE software team).

Comment: For more information on post deletion, see the network Meta:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 6):

If a question gets on hold (gets "closed"), it is automatically deleted if it has no upvotes, and no answers, or no upvoted answers. You can find the details in this post: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Comment: my question had an answer before it was closed, but has gone missing. and according to that list, since the post would have fallen in either the 9-day or 30-day category, "no answers" is not a criteria for 9-day like how you say. could a moderator have deleted it with prejudice

Comment: @devalarist: The criterion with regard to answers for nine-day deletion of a post is its having no answers with a score of greater than nought or that have been accepted.